# Python - Text comparison of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where I would like to compare two columns 'text' and 'text_find'.

I would like to create a Boolean flag 'compare' which is set to 1 if the words in 'text_find' are located in 'text', else set 'compare' to 0. e.g.

```
'text' = 'i hate cars'
'text_dins' = 'cars'
```

this will make 'compare' = 1

```
'text' = 'i hate cars'
'text_dins' = 'rabbits'
```

this will make 'compare' = 0

how would I do all this in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows and then compare with `in`. Last convert `True`s and `False`s to `1,0` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) in `new` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['i hate cars','i hate cars'], 'text_dins':['cars', 'rabbits']})
print (df)
          text text_dins
0  i hate cars      cars
1  i hate cars   rabbits

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['text_dins'] in x['text'] , axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
          text text_dins  new
0  i hate cars      cars    1
1  i hate cars   rabbits    0
```

Another solution with list comprehension if no `NaN`s:

```
df['new']  = [int(x[0] in x[1]) for x in zip(df['text_dins'], df['text'])]
print (df)
          text text_dins  new
0  i hate cars      cars    1
1  i hate cars   rabbits    0
```

Comment: How do i find count of words under column "text". eg. 1st row has 3 words.

Comment: Error : wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
New to python so please do let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @KshitijManvelikar - Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984905/count-number-of-words-per-row)